# segmentation fault after popping the element that has been pointed to by

Tags: c++, stl, queue, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
typedef struct { int a; int b; int c; int d } A;
queue <A> q;
A* ptr;

q.push({1,2,3,4});
ptr = &(q.front());
q.pop();

ptr->a; 
...
```

I figured out that this code might cause segmentation fault. because `ptr` ends up pointing to the popped element.

but I don't know the exact reason why this happens. I just presume that `pop` operation interally deallocates the memory for the popped. Is my presumption right? or any other reasons?

Comment: C++ does not have segmentation faults, so there is no reason in C++ that they occur. Instead C++ just says that your code has *undefined behaviour* due to the *dangling pointer*. A dangling pointer is a pointer pointing at a no longer valid object. Undefined behaviour means exactly what it says, a segmentation fault is one kind of undefined behaviour but so is any other behaviour you can think of.

Comment: [std::queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is a container adaptor which uses [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) by default. The doc. of [std::deque::pop_front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front) states _Iterators and references to the erased element are invalidated._ Invalid reference means as well that pointers to that (referenced) object become invalid.

Comment: What that means is you have to copy/move what you pop. You can't keep a reference or a pointer to an object you popped of the stack (it no longer exists after pop has been called)>. So read the documentation on what you use. Side note : stop using `using namespace std;`

Comment: do I have to stop using `using namespace std;` in online PS as well??

Comment: Side notes: 1) [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) 2) [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) 3) [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) 4) [AddressSanitizer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ documents(https://cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/pop/)

`std::queue::pop` is described as

---

Removes the next element in the queue, effectively reducing its size by one.
The element removed is the "oldest" element in the queue whose value can be retrieved by calling member queue::front.

***This calls the removed element's destructor.***

This member function effectively calls the member function pop_front of the underlying container object.

---

so pointing to the popped element is invalid.

Comment: `cplusplus.com` doesn't have a good reputation among some (or most?) members of this community. I'd recommend [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com) instead.